# What is the hotkey to open Screenpresso pane quickly?

Tags: hotkeys

I often take series of action such as taking snapshoots, anotating the them, copying their path or their image bits, ...

And among those actions, opening Screenpresso pane as below snapshoot is repeated very very often in such manner that I need a hotkey to open it. At the moment I have to open the system tray and double-clicking on `screenpresso` icon which is such a pain

How to shortcut it? Say Ctrl-Alt-S

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found myself the solution to do this.

By adding Windows 's hotkey to open Screenpresso, I got the pane opened.

[Why setting hotkey for a Windows 7 shortcut doesn't work?](https://superuser.com/questions/433644/why-setting-hotkey-for-a-windows-7-shortcut-doesnt-work)