# Shortcut hotkeys occasionally not working

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, hotkeys

In Windows there's the option to assign a key combination in the properties of every shortcut (see [screenshots](https://superuser.com/q/433644/20877)). When these shortcuts are placed on the Desktop or in the Start menu, they act as global system hotkeys that can be used to launch a document or activate a running instance of an application.

The problem is that these hotkeys occasionally stop working on my Windows 7 x64 system. They simply have no effect when pressed. I can verify that the keys are set using the free [Windows Hotkey Explorer](http://hkcmdr.anymania.com/) (although I'm not sure whether it checks the system hotkeys table or it simply scans the .LNK files). It's also not an issue of the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>, and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys getting stuck (either physically or programmatically).

The problem always disappears after a while, which is both fortunate and frustrating. I haven't been able to figure out if that's due to a conflicting application being closed, minimized, or losing focus, etc.

Does anyone know what's causing this and if there's a way to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

As explained in [The Old New Thing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/05/28/10421616.aspx), this is a bug caused by a Windows feature. The shortcuts are supposed to be temporarily ignored when an application is in fullscreen mode, but sometimes they get stuck in the suppressed state. Pressing a system hotkey involving the Windows key (<kbd>Win+E</kbd>, <kbd>Win+B</kbd>, etc.) gets them unstuck.